# Adding a Respond Option to Elementor Collected Submissions Form

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using the Elementor Form widget to allow my customers to notify me of any concerns.

I want to add a response box to the Submission page to send them a message when clicking update.

I can't use the **Email** option of the **Action After Submit** because my answer will differ based on what they wrote.

The image below is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Thank you